# Deleting divs via PHP

Tags: php

I'm making a To do application with PHP (school assignment)

At this moment, I can add tasks to the list. Deleting is the next problem. 
The "problem" is that I HAVE to use PHP to delete the corresponding div. (It needs to delete the div i'm clicking)

My question: what's the best practice to do that? (Working with a specific number maybe?)

Index.php

```
<div class="container">

<form action="/Periodeopdracht/index.php" method="POST">
<div class="headerToDo">
    <input class="addText title" type="text" value="Click to add a task" name="nextToDo">
    <input class="clickablePlus" type="submit" value="+" name="submit"></div>
</form>

<?php if(!$empty): ?>
<?php foreach ($_SESSION["todoList"] as $_SESSION["key"] => $toDo): ?>
<div class="toDo">
    <form action="/Periodeopdracht/index.php" method="POST">
        <button value="<?php echo $_SESSION["key"] ?>" name="done" class="done" type="submit" >V</button>
        <div value="<?php echo $_SESSION["key"] ?>" class="textToDo"><?= $toDo ?></div>
    </form>
</div>
<?php endforeach ?>
<?php endif ?>
</div>
```

application.php:

```
<?php
session_start();

$GLOBALS["empty"] = true;

$_SESSION['todoList'] = isset($_SESSION['todoList']) ? $_SESSION['todoList'] : array();


if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
{
    $empty = false;
    array_unshift($_SESSION['todoList'], $_POST["nextToDo"]);
}


    if (isset($_POST['done'])) {
        foreach ($_SESSION["todoList"] as $key => $toDo) {
           if ($toDo == $_POST['done']) {
               unset($_SESSION['todoList'][$key]);
               break; 
           }
        }
    }


?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($_SESSION["todoList"] as $key => $toDo)
```

then use $key as the value of your "done" button, When processing you can just `unset($_SESSION['todoList'][$key])`

you will have to check that the key is valid coming from the post though.

Comment: When I use your code and click 1 div, all the tasks are gone (not deleted)

Answer (score 0):

Add a <hidden> field to each toDo with, the id of the toDo, then you will know what to remove from the toDo list.

Comment: And how can I use the ID in my "application.php" to unset that specific div?

Comment: when you are printing the ToDos you can look if the hidden field associated with it is set.
`code`
<?php if(!$empty): ?>
<?php foreach ($_SESSION["todoList"] as $toDo): ?>
<div class="toDo">
    <form action="/../index.php" method="POST">
        <button  name="done" class="done" >V</button>
        <div class="textToDo"><?= $toDo ?></div>
    </form>
</div>
<?php endforeach ?>
<?php endif ?>
</div>

Comment: Still not working. I'm trying to do it the way @exussum said. Deleting everything is no problem, but I can't delete a specific item in the array "todoList".. 

Any idea how I could fix that?

Comment: As exussum stated. U need to wrap the unset with an `if` statement which check if the key actually needs to be unset

Comment: @DarkBee Indeed, I read that. But I don't see what I have to check in the if statement.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what exussum was stating. U'll need to define in your `HTML` which todo item u want to delete. Atm your just posting an empty button. Change your `html` to something like this:

```
<div class="toDo">
<form action="/../index.php" method="POST">
    <button  name="done" class="done" value="<?= $toDO ?>" type="submit">V</button>
    <div class="textToDo"><?= $toDo ?></div>
</form>
</div>
```

Now if you post the form the variable `$_POST['done']` will contain the task that is completed. Now the check this :

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['done']) {
        foreach ($_SESSION["todoList"] as $key => $toDo) {
           if ($toDo == $_POST['done']) {
               unset($_SESSION['todoList'][$key]);
               break; //terminates the loop as we found the correct item
           }
        }
        $empty = empty($_SESSION["todoList"]);
    }
```

I'm not a huge fan of posting raw values to check whether items need to be deleted.
Its beter to work with (unique) id's if you are using these.

Comment: I changed my code in my post. Added your code in application.php but it still deletes only the one I click and lets vanish all the rest.

Comment: You should not allocate `false`to $empty when U did a submit. See updated answer and u don't need the unshift

Comment: When I implement it, everything stays, including the div I clicked.. :/